# Is there any specific difference between multi site and multi domain?

Tags: multi-sites

I didn't see any specific difference between multi site and multi domain. If there any specific reason to differentiate them?

Answer (score 1):

Multi site is the ability to have multiple sites running on the same code base.  This can be either different domains or different base URLs.  E.g. could be http:/example.com, http:/example.org, http:/example.com/new_site.

This is done in Drupal via different subdirectories in the sites directory. E.g.

sites/default (example.com)
sites/example.org (example.org)
sites/new_site (example.com/new_site)

Multi domain is partially a subset of multi site as shown above.  But it can also indicate the same site being accessed via multiple domain names.  This is common in multilingual sites.  E.g.:

http:/example.com/ => site in english
http:/example.fr/ => same site in french

This is generally done by modifying the settings.php file to allow these alternate domains to be used.  And in the case of i18n sites, the language detection settings.

So basically these two terms intersect each other but are still different.